# ckanext-spatial - "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, ckan

I am trying to install "ckanext-spatial" after CKAN (2.7.1) was installed from package on Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the [official tutorial](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/ckanext-spatial/en/latest/install.html#install-the-extension). Everything went well until I ran the following command:

```
pip install -r pip-requirements.txt
```

It turns out there is no pip-requirements.txt, so I changed it to

```
pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```

The error I got is:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-V6w2Vm/psycopg2/
```

To solve this error, I have tried upgrade both setuptools and pip. Neither of them worked.

**Updated**: It turns out the ckanext-spatial is installed under src folder by default.

```
(default) ubuntu@ckan-ubuntu1404-xlarge:/usr/lib/ckan/default/src$ ls
ckan  ckanext-spatial
```

Now, I can find the pip-requirements.txt file, but I got a new error.

```
Successfully built GeoAlchemy OWSLib
Installing collected packages: GeoAlchemy, GeoAlchemy2, Shapely, OWSLib, lxml, pyparsing
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 329, in clobber
    os.utime(destfile, (st.st_atime, st.st_mtime))
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some directory confusion here, which is why you don't see `pip-requirements.txt`.

First you need to activate your python environment:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
```

Then step 1 of the tutorial:

```
pip install -e "git+https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-spatial.git#egg=ckanext-spatial"
```

Then you need to do:

```
cd ckanext-spatial
```

before doing:

```
pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the folder after going back to the src folder. However, I still got a error with pip install -r pip-requirements.txt

Comment: Turns out I need to switch to the root user outside the virtual env and run the command again.

Comment: It sounds like this has been caused because you previously used sudo or the root user when installing python packages into this virtualenv. Once you've used it once you have to use it every time. In this situation, I'd suggest you delete the virtualenv /usr/lib/ckan/default and re-install the python modules - i.e. for ckan, extensions and their requirements - following the instructions.